# How to ignore keys which are not required for room entity

Tags: android, json, android-room

I am trying to create a room entity class. But there are some json object which I don't need. So I am confuse how to ignore those objects.

Below is the JSON:

```
     {  
       "batchcomplete":true,
       "continue":{  
          "gpsoffset":10,
          "continue":"gpsoffset||"
       },
       "query":{  
          "redirects":[  
             {  
                "index":4,
                "from":"Sachin Tyagi",
                "to":"Solhah Singaarr"
             },
             {  
                "index":3,
                "from":"Sachin The Film",
                "to":"Sachin: A Billion Dreams"
             }
          ],
          "pages":[  
             {  
                "pageid":57570,
                "ns":0,
                "title":"Sachin Tendulkar",
                "index":1,
                "thumbnail":{  
                   "source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Sachin_Tendulkar_at_MRF_Promotion_Event.jpg/50px-Sachin_Tendulkar_at_MRF_Promotion_Event.jpg",
                   "width":50,
                   "height":45
                },
                "terms":{  
                   "description":[  
                      "Indian cricketer"
                   ]
                }
}
```

I tried to use @Ignore also but that doesn't work for me.

Here is my Entity class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "ResponseEntity")
public class PageDetailEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Ignore
    @ColumnInfo(name = "batchcomplete")
    private boolean batchcomplete;
    @Ignore
    @TypeConverters(ContinueModelConverter.class)
    public List<ContinueModel> mContinue;

    @TypeConverters(QueryModelConverter.class)
    private List<QueryModel>queryModel;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isBatchcomplete() {
        return batchcomplete;
    }

    public void setBatchcomplete(boolean batchcomplete) {
        this.batchcomplete = batchcomplete;
    }

    public List<ContinueModel> getmContinue() {
        return mContinue;
    }

    public void setmContinue(List<ContinueModel> mContinue) {
        this.mContinue = mContinue;
    }

    public List<QueryModel> getQueryModel() {
        return queryModel;
    }

    public void setQueryModel(List<QueryModel> queryModel) {
        this.queryModel = queryModel;
    }
}
```

I only need pages array. Can somebody guide me how do I create my entity class with only pages array for room.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Ignore` annotation which is from

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Ignore
```

Room will not persist the fields that are annotated with `@Ignore`.

```
@Ignore
public String name;
```